# CentOS Tuned Equivalent For Debian

Tags: debian, performance, kernel

Running a few systems, a few are Debian which have been great. I have on the CentOS boxes tuned(tuned-adm) installed and setup for throughput. I searched all over Google and only found some articles on tweaking the Kernel for better TCP performance through issuing/altering multiple sysctl properties and buffers. Does anyone know of or found a tuned tool for Debian or a tuned equivalent tool for Debian so i can tweak the system for throughput? Or should i run through the 2 main articles i found on tweaking the kernel for TCP performance?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an excellent post on [understanding Red Hat's tuning profiles](https://serverfault.com/questions/518629/understanding-redhats-recommended-tuned-profiles/518709#518709).  You should be able to replicate the Throughput settings, under Debian, by adjusting the following sysctl values:

```
kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 10000000
kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns = 15000000
vm.dirty_ratio = 40
```

You'll also want to ensure the kernel is using the `deadline` scheduler.