# multipath, device mapper, and disk i/o scheduler

Tags: linux, multipath, device-mapper

We have two machines with a multi path SAS controller, each with 12 physical disks attached.

We were looking into some I/O speed oddness, and noticed that on one machine, where /dev/mpath/mpath*p1 maps to dm-13 through dm-24 in various ways, dm-13 and dm-14 have an io scheduler of "cfq" in place. The other dm devices in that list have "none" and it appears to not be able to be changed.

I believe the other devices are presented as a different set of dm-* mappings, and those DO have cfq set.

On the other machine, none of the devices selected to be in /dev/mpath/mpath*p1 have corresponding dm devices with a scheduler set.

I'm sort of out of my element here, but since iostat DOES show that some of the requests are being merged on dm-13 and dm-14 of the first box, and none of the others on either box, I suspect we are paying some price for this.

Am I digging in the wrong hole, or is this an issue? If so, how can I fix it, since `echo cfq > /sys/block/dm-15/queue/scheduler` does not have any effect when "none" is the only currently listed option?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question.

We have a slightly unusual setup perhaps, where /dev/mapper/mpatha is the whole disk and /dev/mapper/mpathap1 is the first partition on that disk.

Since we built the software raid array using /dev/mapper/mpath?p1 devices, these never have a scheduler, since they really ultimately defer to the actual underlying disk, which is the /dev/mapper/mpatha device.

All our /dev/mapper/mpath? devices have a scheduler (which I have changed to 'deadline' now) and all /dev/mapper/mpath?p1 devices do not.  This is also identical to how LVM works -- the underlying disks have a scheduler, but the individual mappings to logical partitions do not.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Red Hat or CentOS, please use the `tuned-adm` utility to shift your profile to the "enterprise-storage" profile:

`tuned-adm profile enterprise storage`

[Understanding RedHat's recommended tuned profiles](https://serverfault.com/questions/518629/understanding-redhats-recommended-tuned-profiles/518709#518709)

Comment: I'm not sure how switching profiles will help if we cannot manually change the scheduler, or one of the two paths to a given drive have different schedulers and we can only change one...

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Restart multipath, set the tuning profile.

Comment: By "restart multipath" do you mean a reboot?  We've rebooted this box a dozen times, and yet some show only "none" as a scheduler, and others show "noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]" -- and we cannot change the "none" ones.

Comment: Stop the service. It's a daemon.

Comment: Note that I CAN change from cfq to deadline on the drives that have that listed as an option.  I'm just confused why some of the multi path pair do, and some do not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33126/discussion-between-michael-graff-and-ewwhite).