# how to read the results about packet drops from crash tool

Tags: linux, kernel, dropped

I have Linux machine red hat 7.2

because the dropping problem on eth1 interface

we perform the test according to red hat link - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/206223

finally we get the following results from crash tool

```
 crash> sym 0xffffffff8152aa5b
        ffffffff8152aa5b (t) __netif_receive_skb_core+1643 /usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7/linux-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64/net/core/dev.c: 3587
 crash> sym 0xffffffff8152aa5b
        ffffffff8152aa5b (t) __netif_receive_skb_core+1643 /usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7/linux-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64/net/core/dev.c: 3587
 crash> sym 0xffffffff81597290
        ffffffff81597290 (t) __udp4_lib_mcast_deliver+656 /usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7/linux-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64/net/ipv4/udp.c: 1683
 crash> sym 0xffffffff81560b58
        ffffffff81560b58 (t)  ip_error+104 /usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7/linux-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7       .x86_64/net/ipv4/route.c: 938
  crash> sym 0xffffffff8151a448
         ffffffff8151a448 (T)  skb_queue_purge+24 /usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7/linux-3.10.0-327.10         .1.el7.x86_64/net/core/skbuff.c: 2413
 crash> sym 0xffffffff815d3d7a
        ffffffff815d3d7a (t)    unix_stream_connect+714 /usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7/linux-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64/net/unix/af_unix.c: 1236
 crash> exit
```

please help me to understand the output from crash , what the meaning about the files path , dose this mean that problem is on the files ?

example from ifconfig about the dropping that increased every second:

```
   eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
         inet 12.1.2.10  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 172.16.3.255
         ether 00:50:56:9f:11:de  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 196320  bytes 12640182 (12.0 MiB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 38071  overruns 0  frame 0  <--- drops
```

Comment: if you do not know how to interpret kernel source code it is highly recommended to start with simple stuff like: `dmesg`, `netstat -s`, `ethtool -S eth1`, `/proc/net/*`. For advanced network tuning you can refer to: http://serverfault.com/a/758004/6244