# Is it necessary for the production server(CentOS 7) to start the tuned service?

Tags: linux, centos7

we hava  a large number of production servers running CentOS 7 with tuned service。
Is it really necessary keeping tuned running？
Or we could  initialize the system configuration file such as sysctl.conf  by vm image or kickstart file

Answer (score 4):

I suggest running the tuned service and setting an appropriate profile for your workload. The settings are applied on demand, so you should have the service running if a proper profile is loaded.

Why is this a concern for you?

See: [Understanding RedHat's recommended tuned profiles](https://serverfault.com/questions/518629/understanding-redhats-recommended-tuned-profiles/518709#518709)

Comment: In most cases, there is only one important service running on the server  after it is generated . example: virtual-host won't become virtual-guest.So why I need keeping tuned running to tune system profiles

Comment: When you turn the service off, the settings revert to the default un-tuned profile.